# how to maintain common date for multiple collection instances in backbone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a collection and the instances of that collection will create dynamically. In this case how can I maintain and change common data in all instances of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the common data in all instances of the collection are models. It's recommended to always use the same models everywhere. Namely, you'd better never create new models in one collection if it's already contained in other collection. This not only saves memory, but also, much more importantly, keeps the model-view mapping much simpler. Backbone doesn't do that for you, but you can easily build some model cache keyed by database PK yourself. You may refer to this terse yet focused [article](http://jonathanotto.com/blog/backbone_js_for_the_everyman.html).

Comment: I have to save some models in common data.